# Is it true that $aH = bH$, then $a^{-1}H = b^{-1}H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let a, b be elements of a group G and H a normal subgroup of G. Is it true that $aH = bH$, then $a^{-1}H = b^{-1}H$? How can I prove this?

Comment: If $H$ has an inverse, then $a=b$. Provide more context.

Comment: What are $a$ & $b$? Beside what is $H$? You should ask your question clearly!

Comment: Is H a subgroup? And are a,b arbitrary in H or in a lager group (say G if $H \subset G$)

Comment: It is not true. Try to find counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $H$ is a subgroup of the group $G$.

Saying $aH=bH$ is equivalent to $a^{-1}b\in H$; so $a^{-1}H=b^{-1}H$ is equivalent to $ab^{-1}\in H$ or $ba^{-1}\in H$ (because $(ab^{-1})^{-1}=ba^{-1})$.

Are you sure that $a^{-1}b\in H$ implies $ba^{-1}\in H$?

Check with $S_3$ and $H$ a two element subgroup.

The assertion is however true if $H$ is normal (try your hand at it). An “abstract” proof is with the quotient group: if $aH=bH$, then $\pi(a)=\pi(b)$, where $\pi\colon G\to G/H$ is the canonical projection. Then $\pi(a)^{-1}=\pi(b)^{-1}$, so $\pi(a^{-1})=\pi(b^{-1})$ and finally $a^{-1}H=b^{-1}H$.

Answer (score 1):

This is true if $H$ is a normal subgroup. This is because there is a surjective homomorphism $f:G\to G/H$ with kernel $H$ such that $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}=f(b)^{-1}=f(b^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not true**.

However...
$$aH=bH\ \Longleftrightarrow \ (b^{-1}a)H=H \ \Longleftrightarrow \ b^{-1}a\in H \ \Longleftrightarrow \ H=H(b^{-1}a) \ \Longleftrightarrow \ Ha^{-1} = Hb^{-1}$$

Then

> $$aH=bH\ \Longleftrightarrow \ Ha^{-1} = Hb^{-1}$$

Can you find an example now where your claim fails to be true?

Answer (score 0):

Untrue.

Hint:
$$
aH=bH\quad<=>\quad a^{-1}b\in H.
$$

$$
a^{-1}H=b^{-1} H \quad<=>\quad ba^{-1}\in H.
$$

Pick up $bhb^{-1}\not\in H$, let $a=bh$.